# How to transfer an object from one state / form to another

Tags: unity

I want to do a similar cooking meal like in the game "Overcooked". Where do you cook a variety of dishes.

[image]

I can not grasp the idea of ​​how it is implemented or where to start. You take an object (vegetable), interact with the necessary "changers" (cutting, cooking). At the end of the process - you replace the model and go further?

What do I need to know? What to use? What to google?

I will be glad to any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways to do this.

1. When you replace a "raw onion" with a "chopped onion" you [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) the "raw onion" game object and then [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) a new "chopped onion" game object.
2. It's actually the same game object all the time, from being delivered to getting served. It just changes its appearance. You can do that by [replacing the `.sprite` of the `SpriteRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-sprite.html) of the object or by using an [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animator.html) to transfer it from one appearance to another.

Comment: SpriteRenderer.sprite it's just for images, right?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer if you are going 3D, you can do the same by changing the `MeshRenderer`s `mesh` value, to a new mesh.

Comment: @TomTsagk what if my 3d object dosn't have Mesh Renderer component? Then I must add that component by myself?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer if your Unity `GameObject` has any 3D geometry, it should have a `MeshRenderer`. As far as I know, it's not possible to draw 3D meshes without it, except when doing something really customised, but that's another story.

Comment: @TomTsagk Probably objects with one piece can have MeshRender? [Screen1](http://skrinshoter.ru/s/070219/BQ68wW1J?a) and [Screen2](http://skrinshoter.ru/s/070219/HyoA3wCV?a)

Comment: @ArtikSlayer on your second image, the object doesn't have a `MeshRenderer`, but if you search its children, one of them has it attached, together with the `Mesh` that gives it its shape. If you were to disable or remove that object, the parent wouldn't have any shape at all.

Comment: @TomTsagk It's ok, that object looks on preview without materials? [Screen](http://skrinshoter.ru/s/080219/k9zCDcQc?a) What if I wanna make same with prefab? GameObject?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer I'm sorry but the comments are not meant for discussion, the preview window is to preview Meshes only, so materials are not applied. I'd recommend following some beginner's tutorials on Unity to get used to how the interface, inheritance and components work. This will answer all your questions in far greater detail than I can in comments here.

Comment: Based on a demo of a thing (automated AI task planning) the Unity team is working on, the Overcooked team (likely) used #1. They're different enough objects that they're replaced (the half-chopped would be likely be visual variants of the raw vegetable: same attributes as the fully unchopped vegetable).